# Find permutation index of multiple lists where corresponding list indices match

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have several date time values:

```
Mon 17h10
Tue 20h30
Wed 21h45
```

that maps to the following lists `[Mon Tue Wed] [17 20 21] [10 30 45]`, a list for days, hours and minutes respectively.

Having all permutations of these lists in order, I am looking for a formula which calculates the index of the permutations that maps the original time value.

For example, all permutations of the date time values are:

```
MO  17  10      (index 0 maps to Mon 17h10)             
MO  17  30
MO  17  45
MO  20  10
MO  20  30
MO  20  45
MO  21  10
MO  21  30
MO  21  45
TU  17  10
TU  17  30
TU  17  45
TU  20  10      
TU  20  30      (index 13 maps to Tue 20h30)                
TU  20  45
TU  21  10
TU  21  30
TU  21  45
WE  17  10
WE  17  30
WE  17  45
WE  20  10
WE  20  30
WE  20  45
WE  21  10      
WE  21  30
WE  21  45      (index 26 maps to Wed 21h45)
```

And at (zero based) indices 0, 13 and 26 we find the original time values.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what it is that you're looking for. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, order all three lists as $(Day_0, Day_1, ..., Day_{n_1-1})$, $(Hour_0, Hour_1, ..., Hour_{n_2-1})$, $(Minute_0, Minute_1, ... Minute_{n_3-1})$.

Your lists have $Day_0=Monday$, $Hour_0=17$, $Minute_0=10$ and $n_1=n_2=n_3=3$.

$(Day_i,Hour_j,Minute_k)$ is associated with index $in_2n_3+jn_3+k$.

And index $l$ is associated with $Day_i$, $Hour_j$, and $Minute_k$ where $i={\lfloor l/(n_2n_3) \rfloor},j=\lfloor (l-n_2n_3i)/n_3 \rfloor,k=l-n_2n_3i-n_3j$.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!